# Structured Data Reviews Not Appearing in Knowledge Panel

Tags: structured-data, knowledge-graph

Google Rich Snippets Not Appearing in Knowledge Panel

Has anyone ran into a situation where their online directory had structured data accepted by Google in the search result (#2 after the local business) but not placed as a review source for the local business in the knowledge panel?

How did you remedy this?

With all of the following being correct:

1. The reviews are original.
2. There are no errors in the reviews or aggregate reviews
3. All schema and best practices were followed
4. Domain and page authority are higher than the competitors listed in the knowledge panel

Comment: Your reviews are not `all` unique (original) as mentioned and this question is the same as the previous question you asked, simply reworded.

Comment: Also, you haven't followed best practices since the reviews on the page have no direct markup or JSON. But this is duplicate and too specific on fault finding on your website and unlikely to help others as previously mentioned. Your welcome to ask in our chat channel for people to have a DIRECT look at your site, which in this case it needs.